# Is this the right way to call a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This is a part of my document:

```
function MyFunction() {
    var x=""

    if (x=1) {
        OnBtnPbDemo_SwitchChn1(1); //This is a function
    } else {
        OnBtnPbDemo_SwitchChn1(0); //This is another function
    }
}
```

I want to know if this is the right way to call the functions inside the condition.
Thank you very much.

Comment: There is no difference between calling functions outside or inside conditions. Your code however has a couple of other problems: 1) You are *assigning* `1` to `x`, you don't *compare* `x` to `1`. 2) `x` will never be `1` since you assign an empty string to it. Assuming you get the `x` from somewhere else actually, you can omit the whole `if` statement and use the conditional operator: `OnBtnPbDemo_SwitchChn1(x == 1 ? 1 : 0);`.

Comment: @Ilan: You are right, it doesn't make sense, but you cannot just assume that the OP's code is different. You might have edited out the very problem the OP has!

Comment: You only call one function, the arguments are different based on the results of the conditional.

Comment: @FelixKling OK lesson learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you mean about the "right" way of calling, but you can call functions wherever as long as they're available in the scope.

You can actually shorten what you've written to this too:

```
function MyFunction () {
    var x = "";
    OnBtnPbDemo_SwitchChn1(x === 1 ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Unless you're actually changing the `x` variable inside your function however, it'll never run with `1` as the param.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, calling functions is the same no matter where you are calling it.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. I know you cannot comment yet, but try to post proper answers nevertheless. The right to post comments will come soon enough!

Comment: Answers should to contain code and explanations. An elongated "yes" to get over the minimum character count does not cut it. (Plus there are at least three problems with the OP's code that need pointing out.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `==` in `if` condition instead use of `=`

```
 if (x==1) {
```

instead of

```
 if (x=1) {
```

if you are going to call same function for the different `x` value, Try this

```
  function MyFunction() {
       var x = 1;   
       OnBtnPbDemo_SwitchChn1(x); //you can pass the x value directly to that function.         
    }
```

if you are going to call different function for the different `x` value, Try this

```
  function MyFunction() {
    var x="";
        if (x==1) {
            OnBtnPbDemo_SwitchChn1(1); //This is a function
        } else {
            OnBtnPbDemo_SwitchChn1_another(0); //This is another function
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko this is one of the error, OP need to change that.

Comment: the main question isn't answered yet

Answer (score -2):

You are calling same function twice, Instead just call the function once with the value 1/0 in it.

```
function MyFunction() {
//Check and find value of x
if(x=="somevalue") //true condition
{
   x=1;
}
else{
x=0;
}
OnBtnPbDemo_SwitchChn1(x);
}
```

Comment: FYI, your code has a syntax error and is unconventionally formatted.